# Can't see Windows partition in Wubi install

Tags: 11.10, windows, filesystem, wubi, files

I installed Ubuntu as dual boot using Wubi. All seems fine, only I can't see the files on my hard drive.

Do I need to do anything special to mount it, or similar?
In the Nautilus file browser (top left under the Dash Home button) I see on the left hand side Devices (with System_DRV and a recovery partition shown), Computer (with Home, Desktop...etc) and Network.

Everything in Computer seems empty, except File System, which shows content specific to Ubuntu. Can't see anything on the Windows Network either...
Looking forward to learning.

PS I have **Windows 7 Ultimate x64** installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get files and directory in windows drive (C:) under filesystem/host. Other drive/partitions should be mounted automatically (if it's not recovery partition). Maybe this topic has been discussed before in this forum.